# Can't center the TextView using RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I've got an issue with my TextView, I just can't center it. Here's what it should look like : [image]

And it's actually look like that
[image]

Here's my XML code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitudeTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityNameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: _android:layout_centerInParent="true"_ and _android:gravity="center"_ are missing.

Comment: how to inflate your list item?

Comment: please add layout_weight=1 for each textview and it will automatically take the space according to their weight.. I am sure this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Below technique work for me.That is:
Use your first `TextView` as `left` orient and middle `TextView` as `center` oriented and last `TextView` as `right` oriented and apply `weight` for each `TextView`.

Your code it would be like this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Linearlayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        orientation=vertical
        weightsum=3
>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magnitudeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight=1 />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" 
            android:layout_weight=1/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" 
            android:layout_weight=1/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation along with a `weightsum` of 3 for the children text view would give you a light and more reliable solution, doing it like the following:

```
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/magnitudeTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="test"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cityNameTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="test"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dateTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Now each of your text views will take exactly 1/3 of the whole screen width, if you want the center one to be bigger you can play with the `layout_weight` value in each of the text view to match your desired design.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `RelativeLayout` you can use `LinearLayout` in which you can set the `weightsum` to 3 that will give you more reliable solution. Every `TextView` will get the equal amount of space in a row.

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal LinearLayout would provide a better and lighter solution for your problem. What you'd do is wrap your three textviews in it, then use `layout_width=wrap_content` for the ones to the left and right and `layout_width=0dp
layout_weight=1`

for the middle one

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a linear layout with weights would suit these kinds of needs, the system will automatically divide the screen into parts depending on the weightsum you mentioned

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:weightSum = "5"
     android:orientation = "horizontal"
     />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/magnitudeTV"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight = "1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/cityNameTV"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight = "3"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dateTV"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight = "1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tinker around with margins and weights as you like, this is the general idea

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitudeTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="sdf34 "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityNameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/magnitudeTV"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="dasdasdsadasdds"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cityNameTV"
        android:id="@+id/dateTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="fg25111dfg"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>




but according to me it is not a good solution for this you can con-catenate all the three strings and than set the final string to one single text view as mentioned below:


  String final_string = distance +" "+string_2  +" "+string_3;
    textView.setText(final_string);
```